# gsub for loop creates a repeated character string

Tags: r, string, for-loop, gsub

I have this dataframe:

```
test2 <- structure(list(AU = c("MEISYARA D;GUSWENRIVO I;SINGHAM GV", "VANGALA RM;LOSHALI A;BASA KS;CH G;MASTHAN S;GANACHARI BC;MUNGALA SR;TADAKAMADLA J;TADAKAMADLA SK;BALLA SB", 
                               "SEBASTIAN S;FRANCO A;MÂNICA S", "HUO D-M;MAO X-Y;MO W-W;ZHAO F-M;DU M;SUN R-R", 
                               "KIHARA EN;KARANJA SM;WANZALA P;WAGAIYU EG", "LIANG CT;HIGGINS D;ASHAR A", 
                               "SINDI MA;AL-SEBAEI MO;BAMASHMOUS MS", "PALOMINO-SOTO M;CARRANZA-SAMANEZ K;DULANTO-VARGAS J;QUEZADA-MARQUEZ MM;FONSECA GM;RAMIREZ-WONG F", 
                               "PANCI V;HACKMAN L", "STEVENS DW;DUNN MR;MILLS VS;BOWDEN DA;MCMILLAN PJ;HART AC;CHIN C;DAVEY NK;PINKERTON MH", 
                               "ŠVÁBOVÁ NEE UHROVÁ P;BEŇUŠ R;CHOVANCOVÁ NEE KONDEKOVÁ M;VOJTUŠOVÁ A;NOVOTNÝ M;THURZO A", 
                               "RIAZ S;KHAMIS MF;ABDULLAH JY;AHMAD WMAW;ALAM MK", "FAN F;KE W;DAI X;SHI L;LIU Y;LIN Y;CHENG Z;ZHANG Y;CHEN H;DENG Z", 
                               "CASTILLO-ALONSO C;TABILO L;LÓPEZ-LÁZARO S", "ROBERTS G;LUCAS VS;CAMILLERI S;JAYARAMAN J;KASPER KA;LEWIS JM", 
                               "BU W-Q;GUO Y-X;ZHANG D;DU S-Y;HAN M-Q;WU Z-X;TANG Y;CHEN T;GUO Y-C;MENG H-T", 
                               "TANAKA S;KARIBE H;KATO Y;KOMATSUZAKI A;SEKIMOTO T;SHIMOMURA-KUROKI J", 
                               "KLINGBERG G;BENCHIMOL D;BERLIN H;BRING J;GORNITZKI C;ODEBERG J;TRANÆUS S;TWETMAN S;WERNERSSON E;ÖSTLUND P;DOMEIJ H", 
                               "TSOGTSAIKHAN K;HATANO Y;KOSAKA M;YOSHIDA K;MINJUUR T;GARIDKHUU A;SASAKI K;SUZUKI T", 
                               "LOPATIN O;BARSZCZ M;WOŹNIAK KJ", "SINGH M", "VILA-BLANCO N;VARAS-QUINTANA P;TOMÁS I;CARREIRA MJ", 
                               "GIRIJAN P;BOEDI R;MÂNICA S;FRANCO A", "KAVYA S;PRABHU S;ADYANTHYA S;MIQDAD S;ABDULLA R;JAYARAJAN D", 
                               "HINTON MS;MCMILLAN BR;HERSEY KR;LARSEN RT", "HASSAN A;ELHOSENY M;KAYED M", 
                               "JAYAPRIYA T;KELUSKAR V;SRIDHAR M;LOKESH KUMAR S;FERNANDES A", 
                               "NUZZOLESE E;MALERBA G;VELLA GD", "BARRONE J;VIDAL MC;STEVENSON R", 
                               "TIMME M;VIKTOROV J;STEFFENS L;STREETER A;KARCH A;SCHMELING A", 
                               "ALWOHAIBI RN;ALMAIMONI RA;ALSHREFY AJ;ALMUSAILET LI;ALHAZZAA SA;MENEZES RG", 
                               "EL-DESOUKY SS;KABBASH IA", "ANDERSEN IL;OCEPEK M;THINGNES SL;NEWBERRY RC", 
                               "WANG C;TIAN ZK;WEN D;QU W;XU R;LIU Y;JIA H;TANG X;LI J;ZHA L;LIU Y", 
                               "MORGAN J", "SALAZAR-VALENZUELA L;LÓPEZ-LÁZARO S;AGUAYO-CÁDIZ JE;CAPITANEANU C;FONSECA GM", 
                               "MAHABALA KY;NATARAJAN S;MAHMOOD MT;NAYAK AP;RAO A", "BJELOPAVLOVIC M;REDER SR;FRITZEN I;BROCKMANN MA;HARDT J;PETROWSKI K", 
                               "LORETO DBL;BARROS BÁCD", "WALIA M;BHATI K;GULLAIYA J", "ARROYO-BOTE S;MARTÍNEZ-ARROYO C;GALLEGO-ÁLVAREZ MÁ;ARROYO-BOTE C;MANZANARES-CÉSPEDES MC", 
                               "SOORNEEDI N;VENKATACHALAIAH A;MANIKYA S;DASARI A;GADDAM B;LATHA A", 
                               "PALMELA PEREIRA CM;DOS SANTOS AR;GONÇALVES CR;NUSHI V;COUTINHO F;SALVADO E SILVA FJ;DE SOUSA SANTOS RFV", 
                               "JAWANDA MK;GUPTA S;SANDHU H;ESCOBEDO RLO;BHULLAR HS;HAMZA M", 
                               "HARUDIN MH;FRANCO A;JAFFAR N;NOOR MHM;IBRAHIM MA;MANICA S", 
                               "KUHNEN B;FERNANDES CMS;BARROS F;SCARSO FILHO J;GONÇALVES M;SERRA MC", 
                               "VODANOVIĆ M;SUBAŠIĆ M;MILOŠEVIĆ DP;GALIĆ I;BRKIĆ H", 
                               "RAMKUMAR J;GANESH R;VINAY J", "RIVERA-MENDOZA F;ESPINOZA-SILVA PV;FONSECA GM", 
                               "PEREIRA CP;SANTOS R;NUSHI V;LAMEIRO MV;ANTUNES P;CARVALHO R;MAJOR T;ALQAHTANI SJ"
), Author.s..ID = c("57211806807; 57192983097; 36952129500", 
                    "58235484500; 58236398600; 58235265200; 57217734842; 58235484600; 58236171600; 58235043100; 36183085400; 57207799926; 56878742000", 
                    "58235287100; 57205450144; 57189010056", "57215812605; 58519454000; 57924026600; 57924660300; 57829018800; 58519185900", 
                    "57195633934; 6506257821; 6508066300; 6602243600", "58195847100; 15135714000; 58195400400", 
                    "57218218739; 6602870096; 57190741097", "58307513800; 58308177600; 58022245400; 57192995591; 35190337400; 35520201500", 
                    "58484954800; 55185444800", "7401571955; 7402116738; 25651855700; 8552552500; 7101707095; 7201706201; 58303547300; 58569857500; 7003793212", 
                    "57416602300; 6701772603; 57416602400; 58080360400; 58081085000; 36028646100", 
                    "57203321439; 55357687600; 24833021600; 55163807800; 7401492628", 
                    "56727508100; 57218226768; 35932019300; 57203955437; 56668190400; 58081759100; 58082278400; 57840021300; 57189326786; 36839218900", 
                    "58544769500; 58544603300; 46861416800", "57061571400; 8042276500; 6701854111; 51565457300; 26532954500; 56764949400", 
                    "57391780400; 57188842428; 57203335815; 57215374469; 57203317671; 58191839100; 58192302000; 35236150000; 56009909700; 55916628500", 
                    "57194377552; 7003893659; 56539124800; 55318758500; 56441159900; 7004885391", 
                    "55900416400; 57207514529; 57194834663; 6701764799; 57039166200; 58352179300; 6602247508; 57203616204; 58182056400; 56730646000; 58478877100", 
                    "57428699300; 56797610300; 55957033800; 57429757800; 58141532500; 12761531400; 7404487919; 55731667900", 
                    "56898875600; 57224073300; 26640785000", "57195629545", "57205495992; 57217653844; 7005882178; 15061137300", 
                    "58136445000; 57210935896; 57189010056; 57205450144", "58540862700; 25522097000; 58540160600; 57423908600; 57195430892; 58540862800", 
                    "57783544200; 7006925639; 55206855800; 16245238300", "57220773969; 57148260400; 14422375000", 
                    "58074312500; 6504295343; 57204201957; 57268460000; 57901658300", 
                    "56056565700; 6602086533; 57198019376", "58507483800; 56237340500; 7402601773", 
                    "56072719400; 58132576500; 57297746300; 55147892100; 57223444197; 7003946207", 
                    "57904670600; 57904055400; 57904270300; 57904670700; 57904471800; 55517099900", 
                    "57194481538; 16835094000", "7101937964; 35750447700; 55330827100; 7005305192", 
                    "57209341512; 58108459600; 57203920354; 57221468725; 57919847100; 57857535000; 57919671100; 57914942600; 56928003400; 54786023300; 55850166100", 
                    "57700221200", "57539490700; 46861416800; 57540135000; 57195464981; 35190337400", 
                    "57552704200; 57903377000; 58562326200; 57194032731; 57191113816", 
                    "57222986450; 57338272500; 58451580100; 7003454067; 56236335200; 8904910000", 
                    "57209570307; 58453037100", "57325475900; 57465984000; 57396827200", 
                    "56203448200; 57855205700; 57855205800; 57855831000; 57205131975", 
                    "57219023505; 58537713700; 57189588884; 58537055700; 57559779600; 58537055800", 
                    "55433307900; 58186424700; 58070106900; 58185591700; 58185926500; 58186424800; 56979441000", 
                    "55556592000; 57213338080; 58144251500; 58295221000; 58292275300; 57218176879", 
                    "57192662543; 57205450144; 58157816800; 57193712434; 55358169200; 57189010056", 
                    "57221841980; 50261506600; 57221849486; 6504233232; 7202320517; 54917611300", 
                    "12446817300; 6508382225; 57211558771; 57202373100; 6701830546", 
                    "58236897700; 58237381400; 56631932700", "57194795258; 57777793500; 35190337400", 
                    "55433307900; 56979441000; 58185591700; 58145498900; 58145499000; 58145697100; 58145089200; 56450570300"
)), row.names = c(NA, -50L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

What I want to do is identify is there are a different name in the test2$AU coming from 1 test2$Author.s..ID. So I make this script:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)
au <- strsplit(test2$AU, ";")
author_ids <- strsplit(test2$Author.s..ID, ";")

max_elements <- max(lengths(au), lengths(author_ids))


au <- lapply(au, function(x) c(x, rep(NA, max_elements - length(x))))
author_ids <- lapply(author_ids, function(x) c(x, rep(NA, max_elements - length(x))))

author_data <- data.frame(
  AU = unlist(au, use.names = FALSE),
  Author.s..ID = unlist(author_ids, use.names = FALSE)
)

author_data <- na.omit(author_data)
author_data$Author.s..ID <- gsub(" ","", author_data$Author.s..ID)
author_data <- unique(author_data)


mismatches <- author_data %>%
  group_by(Author.s..ID) %>%
  summarize(AU_count = n_distinct(AU))


mismatches <- mismatches %>%
  filter(AU_count > 1)

if (nrow(mismatches) > 0) {
  print(mismatches)
} else {
  cat("No mismatches or variations found.")
}
```

Then I make a for loop to replace everything that has a mismatch:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(mismatches)) {
  q <- mismatches[i, 1]
  rows <- author_data[which(author_data$Author.s..ID == as.character(q)), ]
  for (y in 1:nrow(rows)) {
    name_replaced <- rows$AU[2:y]
    name_fixed <- rows$AU[1]
    for (j in 1:nrow(test2)) {
      for (k in 1:length(name_replaced)) {
        if (grepl(name_replaced[k], test2$AU[j])) {
          test2$AU[j] <- gsub(name_replaced[k], name_fixed, test2$AU[j])
        } else {test2$AU[j] <- test2$AU[j]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The for loop I made creates a weird string sub that repeates the characters, if i tried to run the loop, I still have a mismatch and the output still is not right.

```
author_data[which(author_data$Author.s..ID == "56979441000"),]
```

Where did I go wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Dear @Rizky Merdietio, (1) could you try to simplify your example to be more focused on the actual problem? (2) when the gsub produces a repeated string, it is probably because you are not replacing what you think you a replacing (so you could try to break this down a little), or because you are replacing more than once. (3) I don't understand the actual goal ('What I want to do is identify is there are a different name in the test2$AU coming from 1 test2$Author.s..ID.' what does this sentence mean?).

Comment: @jkd Hi, thanks for the remarks. It is a bit hard for me to convey what I mean. So what I try to find is:

1. Finding test2$Author.s..ID that has been atrributed to multiple test2$AU
2. If there is an event of that, I want to unify the name that is coming from 1 author ID and merge it into a single name

Comment: I think the answer I provide below should help you to do this. Are there any remaining issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `gsub()` here. I agree with the other answer that you want to put the data in long form. This is how I would do it:

```r
author_id <- data.frame(
    AU = unlist(strsplit(test2$AU, ";")),
    ID = trimws(unlist(strsplit(test2$Author.s..ID, ";"))),
    grp = cumsum(sequence(lengths(strsplit(test2$AU, ";"))) == 1)
)
```

The `grp` column will be used to put the data back into wide form later.

Your issue seems to be replacing the slightly different spelling of author names with the first instance of that name. For example:

```r
filter(author_id, ID == "57189010056")
#        AU          ID grp
# 1 MÂNICA S 57189010056   3
# 2 MÂNICA S 57189010056  23
# 3 MANICA S 57189010056  45
```

As you're using `tidyverse`, you can do that quite simply:

```r
# Replace the author names with the first instance
author_id <- author_id |>
    group_by(ID) |>
    mutate(AU = AU[1])
```

That fixes the problem, e.g. with the previous example:

```r
filter(author_id, ID == "57189010056")
#   AU       ID            grp
#   <chr>    <chr>       <int>
# 1 MÂNICA S 57189010056     3
# 2 MÂNICA S 57189010056    23
# 3 MÂNICA S 57189010056    45
```

Now we can put the data back in wide form:

```r
# Put the data back in wide form
ids_wide <- author_id |>
    split(~grp) |>
    lapply(\(df) data.frame(
        AU = paste(df$AU, collapse = ";"),
        `Author.s..ID` = paste(df$ID, collapse = "; ")
    )) |>
    bind_rows()
```

Output:

```r
head(ids_wide)[-2,] # Line 2 is  long and wraps terminal
#                                             AU                                                                 Author.s..ID
# 1           MEISYARA D;GUSWENRIVO I;SINGHAM GV                                        57211806807; 57192983097; 36952129500
# 3                SEBASTIAN S;FRANCO A;MÂNICA S                                        58235287100; 57205450144; 57189010056
# 4 HUO D-M;MAO X-Y;MO W-W;ZHAO F-M;DU M;SUN R-R 57215812605; 58519454000; 57924026600; 57924660300; 57829018800; 58519185900
# 5    KIHARA EN;KARANJA SM;WANZALA P;WAGAIYU EG                              57195633934; 6506257821; 6508066300; 6602243600
# 6                   LIANG CT;HIGGINS D;ASHAR A                                        58195847100; 15135714000; 58195400400
```

Comment: Thank you! This is so simple yet it solves everything. I need to go back learning the basics..

Answer (score 1):

If what you ultimately want to do is to find IDs attributed multiple times and authors with multiple IDs, I suggest you first tidy up the data, to have one author and author ID per line. Then it becomes much easier to find duplicates:

```r
library(tidyverse)
# tidy up your data
test2 <- test2 |>
  mutate(ManuscriptID = row_number(), # I assumed these are articles or manuscripts?
         AU = map(AU, \(x) trimws(unlist(strsplit(x,";")))),
         Author.s..ID = map(Author.s..ID, \(x) trimws(unlist(strsplit(x,";"))))) |>
  unnest(c(AU, Author.s..ID))

# find Authors having multiple IDs
test2 |>
  group_by(AU) |>
  filter(n()>1) |>
  arrange(Author.s..ID)

# deal with Authors having multiple IDs
# ... insert your own code here

# find IDs attributed multiple times
test2 |>
  group_by(Author.s..ID) |>
  filter(n()>1) |>
  arrange(Author.s..ID)

# deal with IDs attributed multiple times
# ... insert your own code here

# restore the previous data structure
test2 |>
  group_by(ManuscriptID) |>
  summarise(across(everything(), ~ paste(.x, collapse="; ")))
```

I leave it to you to decide how to change the duplicated IDs in both cases.